# Why does COUNT(*) require SELECT permission on all table columns on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I recently encountered the problem that `COUNT(*)` requires the user to have select permission on every single column of a table.
Even though the [spec of 'COUNT(*)'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/count-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) explicitly says that

> it does not use information about any particular column.

It just returns the number of rows in the result.

So if you want to count the number of of rows in a table as a restricted user you get permission exceptions.

Here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE [Product]
([name] nvarchar(100) null, [price] float)

CREATE USER Intern WITHOUT LOGIN;
DENY SELECT ON [Product] (price) TO Intern;

EXECUTE AS Intern;

-- Fails with "The SELECT permission was denied on the column 'price' of the object 'Product'"
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [Product];

REVERT;
```

After some testing I found that even
`SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [Product]` does not work.

Can someone explain what the reasoning behind this behaviour is?
And what would be a workaround to allow the `Intern` user to still get an accurate count of `Product`.

Update:
I would be most interested in workarounds that the Intern could use. So even though creating a View would be best practice for the admin, the Intern does not have this option.

Comment: Have you tried `select count(1) ... `?

Comment: Does `select count(name)` work?

Comment: If you write COUNT(*), extend to all columns of your table. Try with COUNT(name) or count(1)

Comment: @jarlh yes `select count(1) ...` also does not work.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name @JoeTaras `SELECT COUNT(name)` will not work since name might be null and so the result is incorrect.
I know the example does not make perfect sense but basically I have a situation where I do not have a non null column available.

Comment: @Bluuu have you try to `select count(nameSub) from (select ISNULL(name, ' ') as 'nameSub' from product) as TabSub`

Comment: In the ANSI/iSO SQL-92 Standards and up,  a `COUNT(*)` means *"the cardinality of a table expression"* ...The table expression can be a table, derived table, (corelated) subquery, VIEW or a CTE... I wonder what happens if you add a `IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY` column aswell without that you also dont really have a table...The idea behide that the optimizer should have statistics for the cardinality for that table then..

Comment: The best solution is probably to create a view that explicitly excludes columns `Intern` should not see, and grant `SELECT` permission on that. This way, queries work as normal without having to introduce circuitous and unintuitive workarounds and you do not need separate `DENY` permissions per column either -- you don't have to grant `SELECT` permission on the base table in the first place. `COUNT(*)` is probably not the only thing that will behave inconveniently when you start denying access to individual columns.

Comment: @JeroenMostert you should post that as an answer to the question "And what would be a workaround to allow the Intern user to still get an accurate count of Product?"

Comment: @JeroenMostert You are correct that creating a View would be the best solution, I was most interested how the Intern would work around this and he presumably can not create views.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I took the liberty to incorporate your excellent suggestion into my answer, in order to make the answer better suited for future users. Hope that's okay.

Comment: Expanding on `COUNT(name)` example... does `SELECT COUNT(COALESCE(name, 'foo'))` work?

Comment: @pascalsanchez your solutions to convert the null name to something else work. The only part that is not optimal about these solutions is the slightly worse performance.

Comment: @SalmanA your idea is similar to pascalsanchez s solution and it will work. Just with a slight performance penalty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know the reasoning behind this behaviour, but there is a way around it:

```
SELECT  COUNT(1)
FROM    (
            SELECT  P.name
            FROM    dbo.Product AS P
        ) AS t;
```

Of course you need SELECT permission on Product.name, but I gather from your comments that shouldn't be an issue.

Addendum, because I agree it is unexpected behaviour. If you do the following, you are also permitted to execute the count (**if** you have an index on `name` as well as SELECT permissions on `name`):

```
SELECT  COUNT(1)
FROM    dbo.Product AS P
WHERE   P.name = P.name
    OR  P.name IS NULL
```

---

The preceding works well from the point of view of the user who wants something they aren't allowed (Intern, in this case). From the point of view of the DBA, a better method exist to facilitate that user. (Copied from the comment of Jeroen Mostert above:)

> You can create a view that explicitly excludes columns Intern should
>   not see, and grant SELECT permission on that. This way, queries work
>   as normal without having to introduce circuitous and unintuitive
>   workarounds and you do not need separate DENY permissions per column
>   either -- you don't have to grant SELECT permission on the base table
>   in the first place.

Comment: I tried your second solution and it actually works (even without index). That is really quite surprising, it seems like adding the WHERE clause changes the meaning of the count(*) somehow??

Comment: I tried `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM dbo.Product WHERE P.name = P.name OR 1=1` and it actually works and is correct.